# Voice translation -- Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-translate

I am just doing research work, is it possible to convert the voice to voice translation. Which means that, i am talking in one language the other end person should want to translate my voice in their understandable language. Can we do that in any of google api or recommend me if any other api can do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, you need google speech API, you will need to enable this API in google programmer console, there is some trick to enable it, because it is hidden, you need to add yourself to chromium developers list, or something like that. You need also a Google translate api for translating text: there is a project for google tranlsate API v2: https://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-v2-java/
and project for google speech-API: https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2/
you need to acquire keys for those APIs from google programmer console.
You need to convert your recorded files to flac format, bacause it is required by speech API, you could use flacEncoder project: (http://) javaflacencoder.sourceforge.net/

I think this is all you need, to make a translator from voice input in one language to voice output in any other language.

Algorithm:

record sound from microphone, encode it to flac format,
send it to google for recognition via speech API,
when you receive the answer, translate it by google translate API to desired language,
after translation, convert the translated text to speech, you could use Google speech API for that, or other text-to-speech engine, this is open to you, because i don't have big experience with that;

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use `STT (Speach To Text)` API to convert the input voice to text.

The text you can send to a translation API (may be Google or Bing), get it translated to the desired language.

This text, you can send to the `TTS (Text To Speech)` API and it will be read out.

Answer (score 0):

You can reffer [java-Google-translate-text-to-speech](https://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/) instead of [Google Translate API v2 Java.](https://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-v2-java/) because it's free of cost and for [background voice recognition](https://github.com/Mohammed-khurram-Ahmed/SpeechToTextWithoutDefaultUI).

It's an unofficial api of Google Translate in Java.

It also facilitate text to speech.

> Usage of API :

```
    String input="je t'aime";
    Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
    String text = translate.translate(input, Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println("Result :" + text);
```

Comment: Sir, I am trying exactly the same code, i have already included .jar files into my project. But translate function is returning an empty string. Will you help me please?